# Trying to get checkbox label, but getting Object instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a simple few lines of code to get the labels of checked checkboxes and alert the value. But for some reason the alert shows [object Object] for every checkbox instead of its label. What am I doing wrong?

```
function validate(){
    var interests="";
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
           if (this.checked){
               var id=$(this).attr('id');
               interests += $("#"+id).next()
           }
    });
    alert(interests);

}​
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WFzS7/):

Comment: Rather than using `alert` for debugging, try `console.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.text()`:

```
interests += $("#" + id).next().text();
```

Note that you can achive the same result with one line of  code:

```
$('input:checked').next().text();
```

[**The one line code jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WFzS7/2/)

Comment: Maybe `text()` would be even better.

Comment: @bažmegakapa. It doesn't matter here, but I changed as you recommended.

Answer (score 2):

```
var id=$(this).attr('id');
interests += $("#"+id).next()
```

Wait, so you're creating a jQuery object, getting the ID of the element... and then using that ID to select a jQuery object by that ID? What sense does that make?

Aside from that, the `[object Object]` is a jQuery object containing the label.

To get the actual label element, you might want to do:

```
var label = $("[for="+this.id+"]")[0]
```

Remove the `[0]` if you actually want a jQuery object containing the label.

Comment: +1 Just wanted to write an answer that points this out. `this` already holds a reference to the checkbox itself, no need to query for the id.

Comment: Yup, makes no sense now that I look at it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting the object returned by `next()` into a string, which results in `[object Object]` you need to call `.text()` to get the text of the content:

```
interests += $(this).next().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` give you a jQuery object, which gives you "[object Object]" when cast to a string. You probably want the text of the option instead:

```
interests += $("#"+id).next().text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WFzS7/1/